# How does the third argument of React.Children.forEach work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've found out that `React.Children.map/forEach` has an optional argument as `[, object thisArg]` which could set `this` to another object through [Top-Level API](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html)
then I try to run the code below:

```js
        var obj = {
            num : 3
        };

        var Component = React.createClass({
            deal : function(){
                console.log(this, this.num);  //it`s NOT obj
            },
            render : function() {
                React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, this.deal, obj);
                return (<ul>
                          {this.props.children}
                        </ul>)
            }
        });

        React.render(
            (
                <Component>
                    <li>0</li>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                </Component>
            ), document.body
        )
```

it logs three times of `Constructor undefined` and I have no idea why they are not `obj 3`.

so how does the third argument of React.Children.forEach work?

Answer (score 2):

> so how does the third argument of `React.Children.forEach` work?

It works exactly how you expect it to work and how the native `forEach` and e.g. `map` methods: It sets `this` of the callback to the provided value.

The reason why it does not work for `this.deal` is rather simple: If you use `React.createClass`, all methods are **auto-bound**. Hence it is not possible to change the value of `this` later.

Simplified example:

```
var bound = (function() { console.log(this);}).bind({foo: 42});
bound.call({foo: 21}); // logs {foo: 42}
```

That's just how JavaScript works and has nothing to do with React (only the autobinding is specific to React, but [that's explained in the documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation)).

Comment: thanks for your answers on Github and here, it\`s really a weird result for me before even I run  `React.Children.forEach.call(obj, this.props.children, this.deal)`, but now I`ve totally got it, thx:)

Answer (score 0):

Tried it myself. You seem to be right. If you pass a callback directly (or even a callback stored in a local variable), then that'll work as expected. Whereas `this.method` where method is a part of the component class doesn't seem to accept `this` as the third argument which is passed. In that case `this` is always of the `ReactClass.createClass.Constructor` type.

<del>You might want to open an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues) for this.</del> Just noticed your [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4339).